# sys.argv variable passed from shell_exec got shortened

Tags: php, python, shell-exec, sys

i am having quite a trouble when i want to execute my python script from php shell_exec() as the title says

This is my code
exec.php

```
<?php
$my_url="http://reviews.femaledaily.com/moisturizer-36/lotions/nature-republic/aloe-vera-92-soothing-gel-06?tab=reviews&cat=&cat_id=0&age=&order=nrd&page=1";
echo shell_exec("python hello.py '".$my_url."'");
?>
```

hello.py

```
import sys
x = sys.argv[1]
print(x)
```

output

```
'http://reviews.femaledaily.com/moisturizer-36/lotions/nature-republic/aloe-vera-92-soothing-gel-06?tab=reviews
```

what i want expect from the output

```
'http://reviews.femaledaily.com/moisturizer-36/lotions/nature-republic/aloe-vera-92-soothing-gel-06?tab=reviews&cat=&cat_id=0&age=&order=nrd&page=1'
```

Is there any solution to this ? or i should split it into 2 argument ?

Comment: Are you sure you have those single quotes? This is the symptom I'd expect if you left them out.

Comment: You should use `escapeshellarg()` rather than doing your own quoting.

Comment: Are you really seeing the quotes in the output of the Python script? That means something is escaping the quotes you put into `shell_exec()`.

Comment: @Barmar the single quotes are from the shell_exec(), i put double quotes on the expected output, my bad

Comment: But the shell parses the single quotes, so they shouldn't be received by the Python script. Why did it print the single quotes?

Comment: @Barmar i am not really sure, when i see you point that out i tried to swap the double quotes and single quotes, and somehow it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `escapeshellarg()` to properly escape the argument to a command.

```
echo shell_exec("python hello.py " . escapeshellarg($my_url));
```